# Tkinter: root.after(), root.after_cancel()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've got this stopwatch that I'm trying to reset after the count reaches 0. However I am having trouble using the "after_cancel" function. Can anyone help?
What happens is that it continues endlessly and I want to kill the "after" function.

```
def countdown(self):
    if self.totalseconds == 1:
        self.master.after_cancel(self.after_id)
    self.totalseconds = self.totalseconds - 1
    stdtime = self.total_seconds_to_standard(self.totalseconds)
    self.time.set(stdtime)
    self.after_id = self.master.after(1000,self.countdown)
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out... foobar.

```
def countdown(self):
    self.totalseconds = self.totalseconds - 1
    stdtime = self.total_seconds_to_standard(self.totalseconds)
    self.time.set(stdtime)
    self.after_id = self.master.after(1000,self.countdown)
    if self.totalseconds == 0:
        self.master.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

Comment: You don't really need `.after_cancel()` here - you could just as easily skip the `.after()` on the final count, so that there isn't anything that needs to be canceled.

Comment: Incorrect, otherwise tk continues to call the function callback specified in .after()